# Android - Is there a foolproof way to only show possible EMAIL clients?

Tags: android, email, android-intent

In android, you can send an email via the Intent.ACTION_SEND intent, but this will bring up messaging and other things (even if you specify a type of text/plain).

If you want to the user to only see possible EMAIL clients, is there a foolproof, robust way to do that?

Comment: Do you use `text/plain` as your `intent.setType()` currently?

Comment: yes - I had that wrong from memory when I added that to the message here - I'll update the question to not distract folks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17850303/624109

Answer (score 1):

Use `ACTION_SENDTO` and a `mailto:` `Uri` pointing to the email address you want.

If you do not have an email address, then your app should not be trying to limit the user to email. Please let the user [share what the user wants](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/06/28/share-where-the-user-wants.html) how the user wants.

BTW, the MIME type is `text/plain`, not `plain/text`. There's a snippet for `ACTION_SEND` floating around that has the wrong MIME type.

Comment: I take it the mailto (when you have an email address) doesn't break in weird ways out in the wild...  as for when I don't have an email address... I'm afraid that I still want it sent via email, based on the context and material.   mime-type - thanks CW - I got that backwards from memory - doh

Comment: Just saw that you had a link there, cw, so I went and took a look.  Well, I know in one case I won't have the email address, but I know it needs to be sent via email based on the size and content.  However, the other case could work well in the context of an sms if the user wanted to send it that way.

Comment: @user655489: "but I know it needs to be sent via email based on the size and content" --the user could share it via DropBox, or upload it to Evernote, or use any number of other apps and online storage/sharing options. Big may mean "not SMS", and the SMS client will probably tell them that. But big does not mean email.

Comment: hmm, I admit I hadn't considered that!  I'll go see if those two handle the limited html stuff android can send in its spannable thing.

Comment: @user655489: If you're sending HTML, use `text/html`.

Comment: this is for plain text.  It's just your note got me to thinking about the other case.  messaging and other "nuisance" things (in this context) don't respond to text/html mime type, so it wasn't an issue in that case when there is something that supports text/html... but Bluetooth, btw, says it does handle the text/html mime-type, even though it can't handle the spannable stuff Android creates when you use the handful of html tags that html.FromHtml supports ("Unsupported content format" - even though it responded to the intent! but I seriously digress)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, any application can have itself listed. The system looks for Intent Filters that match what application can handle it. With experimentation you may be able to reduce the number of applications that say it can handle the intent or you could try to make an explicit Intent, directing directly at GMail or EMail, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `message/rfc822` as the MIME type?
See first comment: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-email-intent/
See also this: [Send an email in Android selecting only email apps AND specifying attachment mime type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841417/send-an-email-in-android-selecting-only-email-apps-and-specifying-attachment-mim)

That narrows down to Gmail and Bluetooth in my phone. `message/partial` seems to do the same.

I don't know if this works for all phones but seems to be a viable alternative.

Here's test code:

```java
private void sendEmail()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "foo.bar@invalid.com");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "From Test app");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Test test test");
    intent.setType("message/rfc822");

    startActivity(intent);
}
```